# How to save simpleNetwork output from networkD3 in PDF/JPEG/TIFF format?

Tags: r, rstudio, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I am new to Rstudio and have just plotted a network diagram using simpleNetwork in the `networkD3` package. I am looking to save the output in PDF/JPEG/TIFF format for my PhD thesis, however, most suggestions are with respect to saving it on a website (.html).

My code is as follows:

```
simpleNetwork(data, Source = 1, Target = 2, height = NULL, width = NULL,
          linkDistance = 120, charge = -40, fontSize = 12, fontFamily = "serif",
          linkColour = "grey", nodeColour = "black", opacity = 1.0, zoom = F)
```

Everything runs successfully, however I am not able to save the output as a PDF/JPEG/TIFF.

Is there any way I could save it in a picture or pdf format?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I have done in the past using the 'htmlwidgets' and 'webshot' packages:

```
g <- simpleNetwork(data, Source = 1, Target = 2, height = NULL, width = NULL,
          linkDistance = 120, charge = -40, fontSize = 12, fontFamily = "serif",
          linkColour = "grey", nodeColour = "black", opacity = 1.0, zoom = F)
    
require(htmlwidgets)
saveWidget(g, file="name_of_your_file.html")

require(webshot)
webshot("file:///C:/Users/.../name_of_your_file.html", "name_of_your_pdf.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes, a picture is worth a thousand words...

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, CJ Yetman! I have already tried doing that, however, the resolution was terrible (both as jpeg & tiff). Is there another way the output could be saved via some sort of code/package?

Comment: When you use the “Save as Image” feature, you can choose the resolution it exports to. Maybe you could use the webshot package to capture a screen capture of the viewer. Or use your operating system’s built-in screen capture ability.