# Plot is showing in the viewer pane, not in the plot pane

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

```r
# install.packages("networkD3")
library("networkD3")

concept <- c("Vulnerability", "Adaptation", "Resilience")

nodes <- data.frame(concept)

source <- c(0, 1, 0)
target <- c(1, 2, 2)
value <- c(76, 48, 42)

links <- data.frame(source, target, value)

my_color <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal() .domain(["Vulnerability", "Adaptation","Resilience"]) .range(["brown", "green" , "blue"])'

sankey_plot<- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source",
                   
                   Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "concept", colourScale=my_color, 
                   
                   units = "Indicators", fontSize = 12, 
                   nodeWidth = 30)
sankey_plot
```

In this above code, I am getting the Sankey diagram in the viwer pane. What should I do to show it in the plots pane?

I am trying to make a simple Sankey diagram, keep having it in the viewer pane, not in the plots pane to download as pdf.

Answer (score 0):

networkD3 creates htmlwidgets, not plots, which are essentially mini webpages, so it will always display in the viewer pane. The viewer pane has a “Save as image” option if you want a PNG ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56088696/4389763)). There are many possible options for exporting as a SVG here on Stackoverflow if you search for them, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57751023/4389763